# Encrypted Mutt alias file

Tags: gnupg, mutt

I use Mutt for email, and I store contacts in `~/.mutt/alias`.

I want to store my `alias` file in a publicly-visible Git repository, but I don't want anyone else to view my contacts.

I can encrypt and decrypt my `alias` file with GPG. How can I make Mutt decrypt and open my `alias` file on startup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added the following line to my `~/.mutt/muttrc`:

```
source "gpg --decrypt --quiet ~/.mutt/alias.gpg |"
```

The pipe character at the end of that string tells Mutt to pipe the result of the command back into Mutt.

The `--quiet` flag tells GPG to only return the contents of the `alias.gpg` file, and not also the *gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key…* message that it normally starts with.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic way to achieve this is by utilizing [**git-crypt**](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt):

1. `sudo apt install git-crypt`
2. `cd` to your repo and type: `git-crypt init`
3. `git-crypt export-key ~/gitcrypt.key` (*Share this file with the collaborators*)
4. Edit `.gitattributes` file and add `.key filter=git-crypt diff=git-crypt` (*this will configure Git to encrypt all files with the extension `.key` before pushing them to the public repo*)
5. On the collaborator machine run: `git crypt unlock ~/gitcrypt.key` (*note that the file is not encrypted on your machine but whenever you push your changes, the encrypted version will be pushed*)

Comment: Was a git-crypt user many years ago. It seems un[der]maintained now.

Comment: You are right, that's a pitty; I didn't notice that the project wasn't updated since 2017...